# How would I get actual values out of this equation?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

In trying to solve an equation $(8 \% x) \%3 = 2$, I used this:

$x \% a=b$ can become $x \equiv b + a \mathbb Z$, to get this:

$8 \% x \equiv 2 + 3 \mathbb Z$
$2+3 \mathbb Z \in \mathbb Z_x$

I then used this:

$a\%x=b$ can become $x|(b-a)$, $x > b$, to get this:

$x | (2+3 \mathbb Z - 8)$
$2+3 \mathbb Z \in \mathbb Z_x$
$x > 2+3 \mathbb Z$

I think a more appropriate way to write it is probably this way:

$x | (d - 8)$
$d = 2+3 \mathbb Z$
$d \in \mathbb Z_x$
$x > d$

Now, how do I actually get values for $x$ out of this beast?

I've tried plugging in some values for $x$ into this final equation and evaluating to see if they are true or not.  3 seems to be a valid answer, but i'm still just "hunting" for answers to $x$, which makes me feel like there must be a better way to actually unravel the thing and get a better description of what numbers actually solve the thing.

Comment: You can't really toss around that $\mathbb Z$ like just another number. Look at it the other way. $8\%x$ can't be more than 8; what can it be?

Comment: Interesting pov, it has to be in $\mathbb Z_8$.  Gotta chew on that a bit...  BTW i edited my question.  Do you approve of my usage of $\mathbb Z$ now? I think it ought to be more correct...

Comment: This ($d = 2+3 \mathbb Z$) may or may not be appropriate in your community; still, I'd rather go with $d=2+3k,\;k\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: my community is "game programmers trying to learn enough math to do interesting things" hehe.  I will take your style over my improvised one, so I won't look like such a buffoon in the future.  Thank you (;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if $x>8$, then $8\% x=8$ so $(8\% x)\% 3 = 8\% 3 = 2$ so this is true for all $x>8$.

This just leaves us to check $1,2,\dots,8$.

> $(8\% 1)\% 3 = 0 \% 3 = 0$
>
> $(8\% 2)\% 3 = 0 \% 3 = 0$
>
> $(8\% 3)\% 3 = 2 \% 3 = 2$
>
> $(8\% 4)\% 3 = 0 \% 3 = 0$
>
> $(8\% 5)\% 3 = 3 \% 3 = 0$
>
> $(8\% 6)\% 3 = 2 \% 3 = 2$
>
> $(8\% 7)\% 3 = 1 \% 3 = 1$
>
> $(8\% 8)\% 3 = 0 \% 3 = 0$

So I guess your solutions are $x=3$, $6$, or anything bigger than $8$.

Comment: So obvious now that you've said it.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Sure. No problem. I was trying to think of a "slick way" to tackle this problem, but somehow composing "mod" operators with a variable modulus is kind of a weird thing to be doing. Case-by-case seems like the easiest route to the answer. :)

Comment: I'm going to have to try and figure out a more symbolic solve at some point I think. I have multiple equations of this form that need to be solved simultaneously. Seems like it might be hard :/